# How can I reference query string list/array params in an Amazon API Gateway mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a template that maps an array of ids from a query string param to a json template. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
{
    "raw_ids_param_value": "$input.params('ids')",
    "mapped_ids": [
        #foreach($id in $input.params('ids'))
            {
                "id": "$id",
                "foo": "bar"
            }
            #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
    ]
}
```

When I make the request, you can see that the ids param is available, but it does nothing when I try to iterate over it:

```
GET /endpoint?ids=1,2,3
{
    "raw_ids_param_value": "1,2,3",
    "mapped_ids": [

    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution: use `.split(',')` to split the string into an array.

```
{
    "mapped_ids": [
        #foreach($id in $input.params('ids').split(','))
            {
                "id": "$id",
                "foo": "bar"
            }
            #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
    ]
}
```

Result:

```
GET /endpoint?ids=1,2,3
{
    "mapped_ids": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to decode the string before splitting by ',' since it is not a legal symbol for http URI:
`#foreach($id in $util.urlDecode($input.params('ids')).split(','))`